# Обновление профиля если на это есть права

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Как правильно реализовать данный функционал.?

Есть пользователи с разными ролями и есть страница "Профиль пользователя"

Нужно сделать так что бы каждая роль могла просмотреть свой профиль.

Но только администратор мог редактировать свой профиль.

На данный момент я сделал что для просмотра профиля существует одна страница а для редактирования другая страница, но как реализовать это все на одной странице, потому что очень много кода который повторяется

Вариант с тем что скрыть кнопку обновления не корректен так как останутся поля которые можно редактировать в пределах странниц до ее перегрузки - что очень некрасиво
А выключать каждое поле если роль пользователя ниже определенной как то очень грязно получается

Как это реализуется на продвинутом уровне, а не на уровне быдло кода когда пойдет то что бы просто работало.

Постарался как можно детальнее объяснить суть вопроса.

Не нужно писать код, просто подскажите в каком направлении думать что бы лучше реализовать данное.

Спасибо

**UPDATED**

На данный момент я нашел решение с помощью js если у меня роль текущего юзера ниже нужной я запускаю
след код

```
 var form = document.getElementById("form_user_profile");
    var elements = form.elements;
    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
        elements[i].disabled = true;
    }
```

Но насколько это правильно?

Comment: А что если, добавить проверку, если ID пользователя(который открыл профиль), будет равен ID пользователя(чей профиль), тогда добавлять ссылку на редактирование или заменять текстовые поля(ФИО, телефон и т.п) на input

Comment: нет
в таком случае у нас все равно много кода 
отдельные поля для отображение отдельные для редактирования.
много повторений некрасиво неудобно

Comment: ну если делать через js и блокировать input элементе. то через f12 можно убрать "disabled" и отправить форму.

Answer (score 0):

Самый правильный способ это разграничение по правам. 
У тебя к примеру есть роли и есть права вот ты и проверяешь не роль, а права к примеру будет условие, что аккаунт администратора может редактировать только пользователь с ролью администратор.

Для примера можешь посмотреть как это реализовано в разных пакетах. 
К примеру https://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin тут неплохая реализация разграничения по правам.